# Deep link path gets cut to 2 segments

Tags: android, uri, deep-linking

Implemented deep linking in my app, but can't quite understand how `Uri.getPath()` method works... It looks like it cuts the path to 2 segments but why?

[image]

Why is that? I can't see any other method that would return me the whole path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the explanation: (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier))

```
                    hierarchical part
        ┌───────────────────┴─────────────────────┐
                    authority               path
        ┌───────────────┴───────────────┐┌───┴────┐
  abc://username:password@example.com:123/path/data?key=value#fragid1
  └┬┘   └───────┬───────┘ └────┬────┘ └┬┘           └───┬───┘ └──┬──┘
scheme  user information     host     port            query   fragment
```

Comment: Thanks! Accept in 4 minutes

Answer (score 1):

according to this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getPath()
it is decode your path. Read full doc for better understanding about Uri